# R does not change the date format to specified type

Tags: r, date

I am trying to create a date variable in a specific format - mdy as below:

```
d1 = as.Date(c("04/01/2017"),format = "%m/%d/%Y",origin = '1970-01-01')
```

However R shows this as :

```
> d1
[1] "2017-04-01"
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I would like to keep the date format in mdy and not Y-m-d. The same error happens even with a column of a dataframe.

Can someone help me in pointing out why this is happening?

Comment: like this `format(as.Date(c("04/01/2017"),"%m/%d/%Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")` ? but this would change the class from Date to character.

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers. Dates representation depends on locale settings. Try USA locale (you may need to reboot your computer)